# Puma using all system memory in AWS ELB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

When using a rails API only app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I can see that the puma server uses 40% + 40% memory for 2 nodes (using load balancer). If I watch memory usage with this command:

```
watch -n 0.1 "ps aux | grep puma"
```

I can see the output like this:

```
Every 0.1s: ps aux | grep puma                                                                                     Wed Dec 15 20:28:24 2021

webapp    2759  0.0  0.5 257140 22500 ?        Ss   15:59   0:01 puma 5.1.1 (unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock) [current]
webapp    2794  0.7 10.9 1525708 436964 ?      Sl   15:59   1:58 puma: cluster worker 0: 2759 [current]
webapp    2796  0.6 12.1 1596588 483728 ?      Sl   15:59   1:41 puma: cluster worker 1: 2759 [current]
healthd  10201  0.0  0.9 1026576 37044 ?       Ssl  Dec03  10:35 puma 4.3.5 (tcp://127.0.0.1:22221) [healthd]
ec2-user 19134  0.0  0.1 164304  4400 pts/1    S+   20:28   0:00 watch -n 5 ps aux | grep puma
ec2-user 19135  0.0  0.0 164304   660 pts/1    S+   20:28   0:00 watch -n 5 ps aux | grep puma
ec2-user 19136  0.0  0.0 119852  2772 pts/1    S+   20:28   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep puma
ec2-user 19138  0.0  0.0 119420   952 pts/1    S+   20:28   0:00 grep puma
```

I can see, after loading the show page of a database intensive task, the memory isn't freed. For example, if the server uses 4% memory, on the next request it goes to 4.5% and it stays there. After another requests, the usage becomes 5%. It continues to happen until the `sysctl vm.min_free_kbytes` is reached, and other processes can't be allocated!

I tried debugging the server through `/proc/[PID]/smaps` but saw that the heap sizes are too large, like 140 MB.

This does happen in the development environment, too. On the first couple of requests the memory usage climbs to 400 MB, then it stays there. Checking for total allocation provided by ObjectSpace:

```
Thread.new do
  while true do
    p ObjectSpace.count_objects[:TOTAL]
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

This shows that the total count increases but never decreases again.

Running `GC.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)` has no effect.

`GC.stat[:heap_live_slots]` sometimes increases and then goes back to the previous state but leaving the heap to the memory.

I also tried `preload_app!` in puma.rb, it doesn't help either.

There are no variables from outside scope that gets modified inside the controller that can contribute to the memory leak.

The main culprit is the query from the database, which fetches thousands of values from the PostgreSQL database. There are complicated relationships as well. But they all are managed by ActiveRecord. And this memory problem only happens on the show page of the items (which is accessed the most by users), other pages doesn't cause any memory leak.

How do I solve such issue?

Comment: ruby MRI generally will not return memory back to the OS. Basically it will use whatever your peak is. Still should not grow over time.

Comment: Hi, If I do about 200 requests to the server, I have seen it grows to 700 MB, and it keeps growing and growing. The server is intended for running longer time, for many months straight without maintenance, but it barely works for some days, and it goes to max memory usage.

Comment: I compiled a ruby (rvm) with jemalloc, looks like the problem is reduced a little bit. Not yet 100% sure, but looks like it doesn't hog memory like before! So it was probably a fragmentation problem? Because the data I'm sending as JSON is enormous, and it has to be that big. Oh and never mind, GC.compact() didn't help before as well...